# Корзина покупок с хранением заказа

Tags: сессия, cookie, php

Есть корзина покупок.

Данные о заказанных товарах хранятся в БД (товар, сессия пользователя). Когда пользователь заходит на сайт запускается механизм:

```
   session_start();
    if(!isset($_COOKIE["sid"]))
    {
    setcookie ("sid", session_id(), time()+3600*48);
    $sid = $_COOKIE["sid"];
    }
    else
    {
    $sid = $_COOKIE["sid"];
    }
```

Т.е. если куки нет, генерируем sid, пишем в куку и далее используем sid для добавления продукции в БД.
Если кука есть, берем из неё sid и используем.

После оформления заказа:
setcookie ("sid", '', time()-3600);
session_destroy();

Удаляем куку, рушим сессию, очищаем бд от заказанной продукции.

По факту работает не правильно, значение sid которое берется разное, где ошибка может быть?

АП. После очистки кук в браузере. 1 заказ отсылается верно, с заказанными товарами и т.д. Если после этого начать оформлять заказ ещё раз он приходит пустой, а корзина не очищается и откуда то появляется еще одна сессия.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 setcookie ("sid", session_id(), time()+3600*48);
    $sid = $_COOKIE["sid"];
```

Здесь ошибка. Кука может быть получена только после обновления страницы. Так что должно быть:

```
 $sid = session_id();
 setcookie ("sid", $sid, time()+3600*48);
```

Comment: Нет, не в этом дело.

Comment: В любом случае, это ошибка. А значит - есть и еще...

А именно:

setcookie ("sid", '', time()-3600); - куку сделали пустой, но это не значит, что она больше не существует. Т.е. isset($_COOKIE["sid"]) === true. Необходимо проверять не только на существование, но и на значение.

Comment: Ошибки пофиксил. isset заменил на empty. Вроде заработал, сейчас буду тестировать. Может ещё какие косяки есть?

Comment: В приведенном коде больше не вижу.